# Load GLB model with Webpack - Three.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, three.js, gltf

I'm trying to use Webpack for the first time and I have trouble to add my glb model. My model is ok, used many times and I put in public folder. I dont' understand console error, any help will be appreciate, thanks.

I'm using three.js r116 and Firefox. Safari tell me same error, can't found the model.

Here a part of my JS code :

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('/assets/models/street_car.glb', (gltf) => {
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });
```

My webpack.config :

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/scripts/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'dist/main.js',
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: '**/*', to: '' }], {
            context: 'src',
            writeToDisk: true,
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        port: 9000, 
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
};
```

And finally console error :

[image]

Comment: It looks like the relative address to your `.glb` file is incorrect. Try looking for it on your browser URL bar. What happens when you visit `localhost:9000/???/assets/models/street_car.glb`? Is there an `assets` directory in the same location as your `.html` file?

Comment: I just find the problem and post the solution. Thanks for your reply ! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just find the problem, add this lines to webpack.config

```
module:
    {
        rules:
        [
            {
                test: /\.(glb|gltf)$/,
                use:
                [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options:
                        {
                            outputPath: 'assets/models/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
```

And don't need to add assets in public folder, they are in my src folder with scripts.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I was working on a solution for you.

Comment: Glad you got it working! I personally prefer to simply keep my assets in the public folder because then I don't have to add rules for `.jpg`, `.png` and every type of file. The less Webpack I have to configure, the better. But that's just a matter of opinion. :P

Comment: @Marquizzo Haha I understand you, it works like that so I prefer to not touch anymore ^^

Answer (score 2):

For Webpack v5, the previous loaders are now obsolete (like `file-loader`, `raw-loader`, etc), and replaced by the use of [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/)

The correct asset module for 3d model formats like `gltf`, `obj`, `fbx`, `stl` etc. is `asset/resource`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this but for a Symfony Webpack Encore application configuration. @MlleBz your answer actually helped me a lot, thanks.
So, with no further ado, if you're looking to implement a `.glb` or `.gltf` loader in a Symfony / React / ThreeJS application, add this to your `webpack.config.js` :

```
// add loader for .glb files (use this with three.js)
    .addLoader({
        test: /\.(glb|gltf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, it will help ! ;-)